# Used function to find the sum of the array elements, I am getting garbage value

Tags: c

I wrote a code for finding the sum of array elements using functions. I have written like this(mentioned below). I am getting a garbage value as output.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int fact(int n, int i) {
    int sum = 0, arr[100];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum = sum + arr[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    int n, arr[100], i;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    int sum = fact(n, i);
    printf("%d", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Questions: How does `fact` know about `arr` in `main`? And what are the contents of the uninitialized array `arr` in `fact`? And why is the local iterator variable `i` passed as an argument to `fact`?

Comment: Lemme check and will update you

Comment: I bet if you compile with a healthy set of warnings enabled (`-Wall -Wextra` for gcc and clang), you might get some useful feedback...

Comment: Yeah, got the answer.

Comment: int fact(int arr[100],int n). Need to change the function prototype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the array `arr` to your function instead of re-declaring it inside `fact`

PS: Change the name of your function to something meaningful like `arrSum`.

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int arrSum (int arr[], int n) {
    int i, sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum = sum + arr[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
int main() {
    int n, arr[100], i;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if(n < 0 || n > 100)
        return -1;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    int sum = arrSum(arr, n);
    printf("%d ", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `main` should check the value of `n` to make sure that it is not greater than the declared array size. `n <= sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])`